# Securing LDAPS service of Azure Active Directory Domain Services with Let's Encrypt certificate fails

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt, entra-id, entra-domain-services

While I was trying to import certificates into Entra Domain Services to secure the LDAPS service. I read the instructions (`CN=<domain name>` etc.) on how to do this. Self-signed certificates were working fine but I failed to import certificates issued and signed by Let's Encrypt. There is no error message in the Entra console. I triple checked the subject and SAN and they are 100% identical to the ones of my self-signed.

Any idea on why certs from Let's Encrypt get rejected? Has anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @August Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 0):

The certificate you request or create must meet the following requirements. Your managed domain encounters problems if you enable secure LDAP with an invalid certificate:

- Trusted issuer
  The certificate must be issued by an authority trusted by computers connecting to the managed domain using secure LDAP. This authority may be a public CA or an Enterprise CA trusted by these computers.
- Lifetime
  The certificate must be valid for at least the next 3-6 months. Secure LDAP access to your managed domain is disrupted when the certificate expires.
- Subject name
  The subject name on the certificate must be your managed domain. For example, if your domain is named aaddscontoso.com, the certificate's subject name must be *.aaddscontoso.com.
  The DNS name or subject alternate name of the certificate must be a wildcard certificate to ensure the secure LDAP works properly with Domain Services. Domain Controllers use random names and can be removed or added to ensure the service remains available.
- Key usage The certificate must be configured for digital signatures and key encipherment.
- Certificate purpose - The certificate must be valid for TLS server authentication.

Please check if your certificate complies with these requirements